# Can multiple relational expressions be placed into the test condition of a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, expression, conditional-statements

I've been informed by Uni Quiz Answers that:
Multiple relational expressions cannot be placed into the test condition of a for loop.

I have complied and run the below code:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i=1;6<i<10;i++)
        cout << "hi\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i=1, j=1; i<10 && j<10; i++,j+=i)
        cout << "hi\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i=1, j=1; i<10, j<5; i++,j++)
        cout << "hi\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

They all compile and run with the expected output.

In the first example, "6 lessthan i" evaluates to 0, and "0 lessthan 10" evaluates to 1,
causing an infinite loop, but it is definitely legit code with no
compiler errors.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
for(int i=1, j=1; i<10, j<5; i++,j++)
  cout << "hi\n";
```

is same as

```
for(int i=1, j=1; j<5; i++,j++)
  cout << "hi\n";
```

Since there are no side effects of `i<10`.

The value of the statement `i<10, j<5;` is the value of `j<5;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all if I've understood the question at all, so please ignore the answer if it's wrong ;)

As you've said, every for loop you've written compiles without any warning/error because the expressions inside the for are correct as at the end, the compiler just has one declaration (int i = 0, j = 1; is just one declaration that produces two different variables), one condition (6 < i < 10 which will produce an infinite loop), etc...

But probably the 'Multiple relational expressions cannot be placed into the test condition of a for loop.' refers to something more specific like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x ++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y ++)
    {
        printf("Hi from %dx%d\n", x, y);
    }
}
```

This time the message "Hi from %dx%d\n" will be displayed 25 times, in this case the code cannot be written in just one 'for' loop as you can see. If for example that x and y variables where the positions of a pixel in the screen, running

```
for(int x = 0, y = 0; x < 5 && y < 5; x++, y ++)
{
    printf("Hi from %dx%d\n", x, y);
}
```

won't do what you're expecting it to do as the 'for' loop will exit after printing 5 "Hi from %dx%d\n" (every time the for is run the x and y variables will be incremented by 1 no matter what while the first will print 5 times "Hi from %dx%x\n" for each x value up to 5, which will be the correct behavior if you want to get the information of every pixel on a screen or of every index in an multi-dimensional array).

Answer (score 0):

Your first 2 test cases you have one condition, meaning (6 < i < 10) is a legitimate boolean statement and so is (i<10 && j<10) which both just ultimately evaluate to true or false.

So, in those cases you are clearly using one statement. Your third test case, however, gets kind of interesting. i<10, j<5 is written as two statements. It appears it gets evaluated as ((i<10) || (j<5)), which is a single statement. The way you have it written, however, DOES suggest that you are using 2 separate statements. I guess it is just a matter of wording.